# How to merge GeoTIFF files of different resolutions and utilize the higher resolution tile data where available

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, merge, resampling

I've got a single 1/3 arc-sec GeoTIFF file covering an area and a handful of smaller, higher resolution 1 meter GeoTIFF files that cover only some of the area that the 1/3 arc-sec file covers. I'd like to merge all the files and keep the 1 meter resolution in the merged file where it exists.

How can this be done? Do I somehow upsample the 1/3 arc-sec file first and then merge them all?

I'd prefer to use GDAL tools from the command line vs. using QGIS interactively.

Here are some details on the files I've got:

```
1/3 arc-sec File Information:

Extent  -78.0005555557935963,41.9994444436071035 : -76.9994444436055119,43.0005555557951880
Width   10812
Height  10812
Data type   Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
Dataset Description C:/temp/geotif_source_files/00.t
Compression LZW
Band 1  
LAYER_TYPE=*
RepresentationType=*
STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=743.75909423828
STATISTICS_MEAN=420.74078674426
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=135.61134338379
STATISTICS_STDDEV=143.83455577482
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Scale: 1
Offset: 0
More information    
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
BandDefinitionKeyword=*
DataType=*
X : 5406
Y : 5406
X : 2703
Y : 2703
X : 1351
Y : 1351
X : 675
Y : 675
X : 337
Y : 337
Dimensions  X: 10812 Y: 10812 Bands: 1
Origin  -78.0005555557935963,43.0005555557951880
Pixel Size  9.259259269220167037e-05,-9.259259269220167037e-05

Coordinate Reference System (CRS)
Name    EPSG:4269 - NAD83
Units   Geographic (uses latitude and longitude for coordinates)
Method  Lat/long (Geodetic alias)
Celestial body  Earth
Reference   Static (relies on a datum which is plate-fixed)
```

```
1-meter File Information:

Extent  319993.9999795512994751,4699994.0000448292121291 : 330005.9999795512994751,4710006.0000448292121291
Width   10012
Height  10012
Data type   Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
Dataset Description C:/temp/geotif_source_files/USGS_1M_18_x32y471_NY_FingerLakes_2020_A20.tif
Compression LZW
Band 1  
STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=503.98089599609
STATISTICS_MEAN=308.54269690329
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=217.19999694824
STATISTICS_STDDEV=77.859161796059
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=70.89
Scale: 1
Offset: 0
More information    
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
X : 5006
Y : 5006
X : 2503
Y : 2503
X : 1252
Y : 1252
X : 626
Y : 626
X : 313
Y : 313
Dimensions  X: 10012 Y: 10012 Bands: 1
Origin  319993.9999795512994751,4710006.0000448292121291
Pixel Size  1,-1


Coordinate Reference System (CRS)
Name    EPSG:26918 - NAD83 / UTM zone 18N
Units   meters
Method  Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM)
Celestial body  Earth
Reference   Static (relies on a datum which is plate-fixed)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One potential solution is to use a VRT. You can create one of these with GDAL. A VRT is a virtual dataset, a sort of blueprint/instruction for an image without actually doing the processing, so no actual merging needs to be done until the data is specifically called. This allows data of different resolutions and band numbers etc to be joined with little trouble.

To build a VRT, check out the GDAL docs here: [gdalbuildvrt](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html). Pay particular attention to the description here as in your case, the order in which you build the VRT matters - latter listed files take priority. So you will want to list them in order of resolution with the coarse resolution first.

So in your case an example may be:

```
gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata 0 my_elev_mosaic.vrt my_100m_elev_file.tif my_50m_elev_file.tif my_5m_elev_file.tif
```

Comment: I'm attempting to use the gdal.BuildVRT module and get this error: 

gdalbuildvrt does not support heterogeneous projection: expected NAD83 / UTM zone 18N, got NAD83.

gdal.BuildVRT(vrt_file,input_files)

Comment: your images have different projections. A VRT cannot support multiple projections. All your images need to be in the same projection before making a vrt

Comment: I'm experimenting with gdal.Warp to change the projection of the higher resolution files to match the lower resolution prior to creating the VRT now...

Comment: @MattR Multiple resolutions are fine, they can me used together. But the projections (co-ordinate systems) must be the same

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I used to reproject all the data to the same projection:

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal, osr

path = "geotif_source_files"
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.tif')]
files.sort()
print(files[0])
# Open the first file in the sorted list
ds = gdal.Open(os.path.join(path, files[0]))

# Get the projection of the first file
first_projection = ds.GetProjection()

# Create a SpatialReference object using the projection of the first file
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(first_projection)

# Set the projection of all the files to be the same as the projection of the first file
for file in files:
    ds = gdal.Open(os.path.join(path, file))
    if ds is None:
        print(f"{file} is not a valid geotiff or does not exist, skipping")
        continue
    projection = ds.GetProjection()
    if projection != first_projection:
        new_file_path = os.path.join(path, file[:-4]+ "_new_proj.tif")
        gdal.Warp(new_file_path, ds, dstSRS=srs)
        ds = None
        os.remove(os.path.join(path, file))
        os.rename(new_file_path,os.path.join(path, file))
    else:
        ds = None
```

Here's the code that actually merges the files:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import glob
import string
from osgeo import gdal

print('Merging the DEMM files...')
# Find all files with a .tif extension
input_files = glob.glob("*.tif")
if len(input_files) <= 1:
    os.rename(input_files[0],'geotiff.tiff')
    exit()
# Define the output file
output_file = "geotiff.tiff"
# Create a dictionary to store the original file names as keys and new short file names as values
original_names = {}
# Create list of characters (numbers and letters) to use for unique file names
characters = string.digits + string.ascii_letters
j = 0
# Rename all the files in the current directory to have unique short names of 2 characters
for i, file in enumerate(input_files):
    new_name = ''.join(characters[i%len(characters)] + characters[i//len(characters)] + ".t")
    # Check if the new name already exists, ignoring the case
    while os.path.exists(new_name) or new_name.lower() in [f.lower() for f in os.listdir()]:
        i += 1
        new_name = ''.join(characters[i%len(characters)] + characters[i//len(characters)] + ".t")
    os.rename(file, new_name)
    original_names[new_name] = file
    input_files[j] = new_name
    j += 1
input_string = " ".join(input_files)
#Build VRT from input files 
vrt_file = "merged.vrt"
gdal.BuildVRT(vrt_file,input_files)
# Translate VRT to TIFF
gdal.Translate(output_file,vrt_file)
# Rename the files back to their original names
for new_name, original_name in original_names.items():
    os.rename(new_name, original_name)
# remove the vrt file
os.remove(vrt_file)
```

Comment: This reprojects all the files to be the same, but doesn't really solve the question you initially asked which was how to merge different resolutions. If this code is relevant you should edit your question to include it, otherwise it should not be posted as an answer (because it isn't one) :)

Comment: True - I added the additional code.

Comment: Awesome. If you think my original answer was the right solution, then hit the tick button. Also, just so you know, you don't need to translate the vrt to a tif to use it or visualize it - this is done on the fly. Glad you got it worked out!